# How to Migrate Neovim from Windows to Linux

Tags: windows, vim, vimrc, nvim

This seems like a pretty simple question, but I can't find a solution. I have Neovim configuration on Windows with a custom init.vim as well as plugins and color schemes. I am able to get Neovim on Ubuntu Linux to load my init.vim file, but there are many errors. Some of them occur because it can't find the plugins and colorschemes invoked in `init.vim`. I copied the folder titled `share` from Windows into `~/.local/share/nvim` on Linux, but the errors persist.

What do I have to change to get my windows configuration working on Linux?

Comment: What distribution and version of Linux?

Comment: Ubuntu 6.1 is the version

Comment: 6.1 or 16.10? 6.10 was released nearly 15 years ago.

Comment: 6.1 cccccccccccccx

Comment: The Neovim project started in 2014 so it isn’t even available for Ubuntu 6.1.

Comment: Please edit the question to include Ubuntu OS version (and possibly Windows version); Neovim versions--both the one used on Windows and the one used on Ubuntu; And the error messages it gives you--but please _[post it as text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), not as a graphical screenshot._ Posting the `init.vim` file contents _might_ be helpful, as well.